# Remove parts of line layer

Tags: qgis, line, extract, delete

I have a shapefile layer in QGIS containing Europes coastlines.

I want to extract only Norways coastline from this.

If I make a polygon layer that overlaps only Norway and then use the Vector selection "select by location" nothing happens.

My tries have resulted in that the entire layer gets selected.

[image]

Comment: So, what is you question? "How do I split a multiline in single lines?" or "How does clip/intersect work?"

Comment: @Erik from the image, it is doubtful that changing to a single line will add breaks at the country boundary

Comment: If you split the multiline using a shapefile containing borders...

Comment: I used the Multipart to singlepart. Then used a overlay polygon and then extract by location. 
Worked perfect!

Comment: @Tobbe if you found a solution go ahead and put it as an official answer to clearly mark that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Give 'clip' tool a try (in the processing toolbox search for 'clip'):

[image]

[image]

The clipping shape is just a guess, for hitting exacly Norway, you can use boundry files e.g. from here: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/countries

Clipping result will look like this:

[image]